# .net core 6 hosted in apache RHEL - failed to connect api with https

Tags: apache, ssl, .net-core, https

I have .net core 6 web apps hosted on apache in RHEL. I have used wildcard certificate. I can browse from browser with proper certificate. problem is : my application consume API with https , while consuming I got tls/ssl connection error. I stored the log in database I found that internally I found http://[domain]  instead of https://[mydomain].

Please help to solve the problem

I am trying expect while log the page visited: https://[mydomain]/DashBoard/Index instead of http://[mydomain]/DashBoard/Index.

Internally I am getting http that's why could not consume any https API, from browser I can see the certificate.

Comment: my service could not listen https://localhost:5001 ( apache RHEL) . how can i do that  , please also help

Comment: Please provide relevant code parts, so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.